# Jenkins does not execute goals for maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Jenkins always shows BUILD FAILURE, but downloads all necessary dependencies. It shows error message:
**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project spring-petclinic: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/ademchenko/spring-petclinic/target/spring-petclinic-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar**

[Jenkis build failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1uOg.png)

Comment: do you have permission to delete the jar from that directory?

Comment: Where can I see these permissions?

Comment: that would depend on your operating system....

Comment: Thank You! This command allows to run:
sudo chown -R jenkins /path_to_folder_with_pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be issue with folder permissions, provide permissions and try, good luck.